# Combining two nearly identical tables in SQL

Tags: sql, inner-join, union

I am trying to combine two tables. Each table has the name of a particular job, and the start or succeed time. The problem here is that sometimes the same job is run multiple times (or at least it has the same name), so joins do not work properly since there isn't really a good identifier that links the start job from one table, to the success of the same job on another table.

Below is a snapshot of the two tables that I am trying to join.

http://tinypic.com/r/2w20phw/8

(I guess stackOverflow won't let me post images yet >.<)
If you look at the two tables, you can see that one job does not start before the other finishes. However I am not sure how to translate that into a proper sql statement that would join the two.

The attributes JOB_NAME, GROUP_NAME, RDF_PRODUCT, FLOW_ID are always the same. Only the JOB_LOG_ID and EVENT_DATE are unique (although in theory event_date might not be unique).

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as this, right?

```
SELECT job_log, job_name, colx INTO table1 FROM table2
```

Comment: O man it might be that simple wow. I have to think about that and see if there are some cases where it could cause issues. I'm not too clear on how the `INTO` function works.

EDIT: The problem is that jobs end at different/unpredictable times. So the row on the 'START' table must match the row on the 'SUCCESS' table - and there is no way to automatically order the 'SUCCESS' table to match the START table perfectly

Comment: I think you have a fundamental flaw there, in that the job_log_id, should match between the two tables, right? If I understand correctly, you have no good way of joining the two tables, correct? Otherwise, you can join data based on the job_log_id---

Comment: The job_log_id is unfortunately different for the job creation and completion. That's my problem.

Comment: One thing we do know about the `JOB_LOG_ID` of the `START` table is less than the `JOB_LOG_ID` of the `SUCCESS` table, and also that the `JOB_LOG_ID` of the `SUCCESS` table is less than the `JOB_LOG_ID` of the `START` tables next tuple... if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest trying to do a union of the 2 tables.